# Posting from Wordpress to Facebook

Tags: plugins, facebook

Is there a plugin that automatically posts your blog post to Facebook?

And only to a specific Page (because I'm admin of several).

Comment: The Jetpack plugin has a module called Publicize which handles twitter, facebook, LinkedIn and many others. Could be worth having a look at.

Comment: I've used Publicize before, once you connect it should ask what page(s) you want it to have access to so you won't push to the wrong account/page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress plugins repository has plenty ... have you tried the [Official Facebook](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/) plugin?

I'd always recommend you search the plugin repository first and then come here and explain what plugins you have installed.